# Unable to use .bar_label

Tags: matplotlib

seeking your kind help to solve this issue i'm facing with bar_label.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
%matplotlib inline

df1 = pd.read_csv('AsiaCases_.csv')
df1.head()

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df1['Country'],df1['TotalDeaths'])
ax.bar_label(df1['Country'])
```

The error i receive:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /var/folders/dc/wq8x31k506vdg85ry9frgbyh0000gp/T/ipykernel_10666/1187241174.py
> in 
> 1 fig,ax=plt.subplots()
> 2 ax.bar(df1['Country'],df1['TotalDeaths'])
> ----> 3 ax.bar_label(df1['Country'])
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py
> in bar_label(self, container, labels, fmt, label_type, padding,
> **kwargs)    2604         _api.check_in_list(['edge', 'center'], label_type=label_type)    2605
> -> 2606         bars = container.patches    2607         errorbar = container.errorbar    2608         datavalues = container.datavalues
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in
> **getattr**(self, name)    5485         ):    5486             return self[name]
> -> 5487         return object.**getattribute**(self, name)    5488     5489     def **setattr**(self, name: str, value) -> None:
>
> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'patches'

I has worked before. Somehow, the barchart plots, but the bar_label stopped working.

Comment: `bars = ax.bar(df1['Country'],df1['TotalDeaths'])` followed by `ax.bar_label(bars)`

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) in the duplicate.